# Storing user data in sessions - from DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

If I have a login system or something similar, I store a session_id and a user_id  in sessions, but any other data pertaining to a certain user is stored in a database. I've seen other scripts where people store other data (*username, email etc*) in sessions.

I was just wondering, which would be "better"? Saving data in sessions from the DB or having less sessions and grabbing the data from the database?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say just store things like user id and login hash in session. Remember not to store passwords or info that is not requested a lot of times by the script. What I mean with my last statement is that you can fetch the email from the db if it is only needed once throughout a session. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store whatever information you like in the `$_SESSION`. I believe it can be up to 128Mb - limit is governed by `memory_limit` which is 128Mb by default. You could change this.

However, as a rule of thumb, I'd store information that is pertinent and/or less expensive than querying a database for - Put another way **as little as possible**.

It will no-doubt vary widely by use, but often, sessions contain things like:

- Username
- Full display names
- Email address
- Id's (user or otherwise)
- Permissions
- User groups
- Hashes
- Form input errors (temporarily, to highlight form errors)

Storing large blocks of data/info isn't advised though for reasons of speed/scale.

If your site/platform needs to scale at a later date, at the right point, you'd be better off looking at [write-through caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) or similar for frequently used/required data (e.g. [Memcached](http://memcached.org/)) and storing the vast majority of data in your DB - where is should be.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is *it depends* and in your case, it probably doesn't even matter.

#### Session approach

- Less queries = faster

#### DB approach

- Less data in session prevents clobbering
- Updates to the DB are reflected immediately without having to worry about simultaneously updating the session

Answer (score 2):

Practice shows it is better to keep data in database (for >= medium sized projects (server farm/really LOTS of data in session) or to enhance security for any sort of project(e.g. shared hosting)). Even user id should not be kept in the `$_SESSION`. Hashes, flash messages, quick settings - that's what ought to be in the `$_SESSION`.

But if you still have a question "Do I need to save session in DB" then most probably you should not keep it in DB.

Comment: You also may be interested in memcache session storage